# Looping over array of string using huge amounts of memory? (in C)

Tags: arrays, c, loops, memory, memory-management

I use a program written in C (not mine) which simulates the chemistry in environments in space. The program is large and complex, but I want to make one very small amendment...

I would like to create an array of 122 different molecules (`species`), and iterate through them, each time calling a function that retrieves the 'abundance' of that molecule...

```
void calculate_molecule(int i_x, int i_y){
  
  double **abundance

  char *molecules[122] = {"H", "He", "C", "N", "O"...}      // 122 molecules altogether
 
  for (i=0;i<n_molecules;i++{
    
    abundance = get_abu(molecules[i]);

    cell[i_x][i_y].abu[i] = abundance[i_x][i_y];

    free(abundance);

  }
```

This works, but uses a **huge** amount of memory! The `calculate_molecule()` function is called 10,000 times during the run of the program. Is there an issue with creating this large array every time the function is called?

(things like the `get_abu()` function and `n_molecules` are defined elsewhere, its only iterating over the array that is my addition)

I have very little understanding of C, only Python, so I'm sure there is some obvious mistake I have made!

Comment: Do you have any issues now? If allocating large memories many times becomes an issue depends on your target. (the target machine, memory size that can be used, allowed run time, etc...)

Comment: @lucas Declare the array with the storage specifier static.

Comment: what here is using a **huge** amount of memory, `data_species`? `abundance`? `molecules` isn't, if that's your concern.

Comment: What is `data_species`? I don't see it allocated in the function so it probably shouldn't be freed there. 122 pointers to string literals doesn't qualify as *huge* in my opinion. If the array is never modified then declaring it as static may make a difference.

Comment: You should post [mcve] and define what is "**huge**".

Comment: If they are actually elements rather than molecules the program might be more efficient to refer to them by atomic number, for example `abundance = get_abu_n(i);` instead of `abundance = get_abu(molecules[i]);` with a dummy entry at index `0`.

Comment: sorry my mistake, `data_species` should be abundance, have made the edit

Comment: without knowing anything else and assuming `abundance` is the **huge** amount of memory you're talking about, could you modify `get_abu` to only return `abundance[i_x][i_y]` since that's the only part of `abundance` you care about?

Comment: @yano thank you for that suggestion, I will try it. I was only guessing that the array of strings is what causing the problem, since `abundance` is freed after each iteration, but maybe it is infact the problem?

Comment: The array of string *pointers* and the string literals they point to, don't take very much memory. We can't see what else you are doing.

Comment: I'm still not sure what problem you're trying to solve. Does your system have limited memory and you're using too much? Is it running too slow? If neither of those are true then you have nothing to worry about. Allocating memory is a slow process, so if you're `malloc`ing and `free`ing 10000 times a second... You could try pre-allocating the memory and reuse it. Or what I was getting at above, only grab what you need, if that's possible. Unless you're on an embedded system with very little resources, the array of strings isn't even a drop in the bucket in terms of memory  consumption.

Comment: worst case scenario, your array of string pointers is 8 bytes for each entry (on 64-bit architecture), each string they point to is 3 `char`s (conservatively assuming each element is 2 `char`s, which isn't true), that's (122*8) + (122*3) = 1342 bytes. That's nothing. That will fit on a 1.44MB floppy disk from 1992 over 1125 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not freeing `abundance` correctly; that's why you're seeing a huge memory use.

Based on the declaration of `abundance` and the `abundance[i_x][i_y]` expression, it's clear that `get_abu` allocates a 2D structure that looks something like this:

```
           +---+       +---+                            +---+
abundance: |   | ----> |   | abundance[0] ------------> |   | abundance[0][0]
           +---+       +---+                            +---+
                       |   | abundance[1] ----+         |   | abundance[0][1]
                       +---+                  |         +---+
                        ...                   |          ...
                                              |
                                              |         +---+
                                              +-------> |   | abundance[1][0]
                                                        +---+
                                                        |   | abundance[1][1]
                                                        +---+
                                                         ...
```

where each "row" is allocated separately.  You have to free each "row" of `abundance` before freeing `abundance` itself:

```
for ( size_t k = 0; k < number_of_rows_in_abundance; k++ )
  free( abundance[k] );
free( abundance );
```

This requires you to know how many "rows" are in `abundance`, though I'm assuming you know that.

A better idea would be to allocate all that memory *once* for *all* of the molecules in a separate operation, then get the abundance for each molecule at each index, then free everything.  So, as a suggestion, I would create two more functions - one that allocates `abundance` for all molecules and one that deallocates it, then just pass `abundance` as an argument to the `calculate_molecule` function:

```
double ***calculate_abundance( char **molecules, size_t count )
{
  double ***abundance;

  abundance = malloc( count * sizeof **abundance );
  if ( abundance )
  {
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
      abundance[i] = get_abu( molecules[i] );
  }
  return abundance;
}

void calculate_molecule( int i_x, int i_y, double ***abundance, size_t count )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    cell[i_x][i_y].abu[i] = abundance[i][i_x][i_y]; 
}

void free_abundance( double ***abundance, size_t count )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
  {
    for ( size_t k = 0; k < rows_for_each_abundance_i; k++ )
    {
      free( abundance[i][k] );
    }
    free( abundance[i] );
  }
  free( abundance );
}
```

So in the code that calls `calculate_molecule`, you'd do something like this:

```
 char *molecules[] = { "H", "He", ... };
 size_t count = sizeof molecules / sizeof molecules[0];
 double ***abundance = calculate_abundance( molecules, count );
 if ( abundance )
 {
   /** 
    * do whatever you do that calls calculate_molecule; the call
    * will now look like this:
    */
   calculate_molecule( x, y, abundance, count );
   
   /**
    * When you don't need abundance anymore, deallocate it
    */
   free_abundance( abundance, count );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this has solved the issue!